# How does Flash communicate with dll files

Tags: c, flash, dll

I want Flash to communicate directly with
dll files. How can I do this?

If Flash works, great! I just need an honest and descriptive answer
Thanks,

REQUIREMENT:
• Work without a server
• Understand what protocol I can use

DESCRIPTION:
• Flash GUI interface
• Stand alone unit
• It has a change acceptor and other hardware

There's no accommodations being made for Flash. I've
got to make this easy for other developers, and need enough info to
draw a diagram of how this will work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i doubt that will "work without a server".
Maybe if you use AIR, but i am not sure that will work.

Flash runs on the host. Which may be a unix that does not support "windows" dlls.
Or the Dll may not work under 64bit Windows 7.

you may at least need a Database-server or an web server.

Comment: that's what I figured. I'll probably use AIR to package it, but I'll still need 'middleware' of some sort.

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to the other answer, Flash doesn't "run on the host" it runs "on the client" via plugins or standalone players.  The server send the client a bytecode compiled package and the client platform executes that code locally.  Flash Player and AIR are those platform.  Flash will communicate with a server no matter what underlying OS there is, but you need to use the methods built into Flash like ExternalInterface (Flash <-> Javascript), fsCommands (Flash <-> Javascript), or Flash Remoting with Coldfusion Server.  You can also use some rudimentary XML requests and posts.

The server simply serves the content and in the case of Remoting flash and Coldfusion swap binary data packets that they both understand.  Coldfusion handles the packets server side and Flash handles them Client side.

As far as DLL access.  Not likely.  I have not tried to have flash access a DLL, nor would I want to.  Maybe if you gave more of an idea what you are trying to do I can lead you in a different direction.

Comment: thanks. I'll post some more stuff. I'm making a Flash desktop App to run on Linux.